# How do I make a function that works with a temporary buffer and returns a new array?

Tags: function, buffer, temporary

My professor gave us this skeleton code to work from and I can't figure out how to write the code for this using the variables declared.

```
// This function scans through the input letters
// and copies them into a temporary buffer.
// The temporary buffer is then copied into a
// dynamic array that exactly holds the data.

char* delete_repeats(char letters[], int size, int& numLetters)
{

    char *temp = NULL;        // Holds unique chars

    char *trimmed = NULL;     // Unique chars with no empty space

    numLetters = 0;



//WRITE THE CODE FOR THIS FUNCTION


    // Return new array
    return trimmed;
}
```

Comment: SO does not encourage questions that can be answered by a basic tutorial on a language or 'do-my-homework' questions, someone who comes along may downvote it. See : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask